# What is the organization called when a group of clans belong to it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the word that describes the classification or organization that has many clans.

For example:

- Members belong to a Clan and the Clan has many members
- Clans belong to a *something* and a *something* has many Clans

Comment: If this runs into a dead end here, asking a mod to migrate to [English.SE] (where it would presumably be tagged [word-request]) might be the best move.

Comment: To second Tuggy, that SE is largely "what's the word for..." questions--it'd be right at home there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @TuggyNE and nitsua60. I've got the answer that I was looking for, but will keep that community in mind for future word-related questions!

Comment: Querent admits this should have been on English language and usage...

Comment: Oh, there's **got** to be a good pun for this one.  I'm just no good at thinking up puns.

Comment: I ended up choosing the term "Alliance". A close second would be "Dynasty". "Confederacy" is an excellent term, however, it did not fit in the theme.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you perhaps referring to the word "**Tribe**"?

A tribe is normally an organization that consists of many clans.

For example, The barbarians of Icewind Dale were all a large group that lived in the harsh wastes in the North of The Forgotten Realms. Each had their own designation, Such as Tribe of the Elk, Tribe of the Bear, Tribe of the Tiger, etc. And each Tribe had clans that while still belonging to those Tribes, were separate entities.

Those Barbarians were still members of the Larger tribe, they just lived in their own clan and took orders from the leader of their tribe.

Comment: Yes, this. I'm currently running a game of tribal politics/adventure (same setting as [this one](https://balazar-bound.obsidianportal.com/wikis/the-land-of-balazar)), and which tribes clans belong to is a super-important feature of the social landscape. Aside, it might be a nice parallel to mention that below the clan unit is the family unit.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer at the current moment. While "Tribe" isn't exactly the word I'm wanting to you, you did open the doors to using more community-related words, such as "Kingdom" or "Empire". I'm accepting this answer as it has led me in the right direction, and it will hopefully steer others as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Nation.**

Beside 'tribe', also consider 'nation'. The [Iroquois League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroquois) (a.k.a. the Five Nations) was a league of five (or six) nations.

[Tribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribe) is not a well-defined term. Sometimes the whole nation is referred to as a tribe, and sometimes subunits of the nation are referred to as tribes.

Each nation was made up of [clans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clan).

Answer (score 0):

Try Folk, Northmen (Southerners etc.), Free dwarves, enlightened, Red- Blue- Axe- People, i hope you get the idea, or use a invented Name like Valar (Lotro).